# First time loading Outlook Web Add-In Error on Console

Tags: angularjs, rest, outlook, add-in, adal.js

I have simple add-in of loading SharePoint data on Outlook web add-in using [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js), [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) & [Office.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx).

My add-in is of Task pane, When any user loads an appointment and select this add-in, it fetches data from SharePoint using ADAL js library using `oAuth` & `REST API`, and manipulates some values in new appointment form.

Here is the Guide link for [Getting Started with adal.js and the Office 365 APIs](https://www.itunity.com/article/started-adaljs-office-365-apis-2144).

Below is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title>My O365 Add-In</title>

<link href="../Content/Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../Content/Custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="//appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-route.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/adal.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/adal-angular.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="OfficeApp">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="Scripts/App.Module.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/App.Routes.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Services/responseServices.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Controllers/addInController.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Similar source can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/matejv1/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3657/O3657-3%20Building%20Office%20Apps%20for%20Outlook%20Using%20Angular%20and%20Material%20Design/Completed%20Project/src).

When I try to load the add-in for the first time it gives below error in `office.js` file, after first call, if I load that add-in again, it works properly.

Error is:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: ConversationId

[image]

This [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/156) is already logged on GitHub and tried all the possible solution. but nothing worked out for me.

Does anyone have encountered such error? I am very glad if you can help me on this.

Thanks in advance.